# Fetching the list of last values from SQL Server database and left join to a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

Is there any way to fetch the list of last value from database? I have a table called `SessionList` with columns `StudId` (`SID`), `Therapist ID` (`TID`), `Date`

I have total of 5 kids with `SID` 1,2,3,4,5 and 10 therapists with TID 1,2,3...

Now all the kids are assigned to a specific therapist.

So kid 1 is assigned to therapist 10, 2 is assigned to therapist 5 and so on with a date when they start teaching them. I can change a therapists for a kid from certain date, for example therapist was with kid 1 in JAN and FEB and now he is been re-assigned to therapist 7 from March. So I have a list of all these records. So one kid can have multiple records in the table and the very last record for that kid will the the current therapist for that kid.

How to fetch list of last records for all the kids from the table. If I have a total of 12 records in DB my query should only fetch 5 records which represent the last entry of that kid in database.

I tired to use LAST keyword. using the join on same table. It didn't worked.

Is there any way I can create a view and use a inner/left join to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) if you're on SQL Server 2005 and newer (you aren't specific enough in that regard).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `CustomerId` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some criteria.

So try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_CurrentTherapists 
AS
   WITH CurrentTherapist AS
   (
       SELECT 
          SID, TID, [Date],
          RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SID ORDER BY Date DESC) 
       FROM 
          dbo.SessionList
   )
   SELECT 
      SID, TID, [Date]
   FROM 
      CurrentTherapist
   WHERE
      RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `SID` - each kid) - ordered by the date.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

PS: Using a column name like `Date` is horribly bad - first of all, this doesn't tell me **at all** what kind of date it is - and besides, as of SQL Server 2008, `DATE` is a reserved keyword (for a data type). Try to make your column names **more expressive**, more meaningful and avoid all SQL Server reserved keywords! (see [official MSDN documentation on the reserved keywords in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx))

I'd suggest using something like `SessionDate` (if this means the date of when the session took place), or `ValidFrom` if it represents the date from which on a kid/therapist matching is actually valid / in place.

Comment: Is it possible to define a column in a `SELECT` like `RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SID ORDER BY Date DESC)`? I'm gonna check that out when I get to work tomorrow. Thought it could only be done like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNum`. Sorry if this sounds like I'm nitpicking...

Comment: @TT.: if you want to be able to select *just* the first row for each partition (`WHERE RowNum = 1`), you have to use some kind of a subquery or CTE - can't do it directly.

Comment: Great thats kind of what i wanted. But instead of fetching the first row is it possible get the row with MAX RowNum value? There are cases where kid 1 has 3 records and kid 4 has only one records.

Comment: @arpanshah: just "turn around" the `ORDER BY` clause - sort by `[Date] ASC` and then select the first `RowNum`

Comment: Oh Yah, that make sense.I feel stupid now.:P Thanks a lot man.